# Accuracy of Cooley-Tukey FFT - float versus double

Tags: floating-point, double, fft

I heard about non accuracy of float FFT, especially of cos and sin function - there are totally different numbers compared with double.

I ask because I re-write some code - Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm; and the results are different. The original project uses double and new one is float. Is that my error? And I write this code from matlab and c++... and little ask the double of matlab is the same like java and c+ double??

```
float  PI=3.141592;
// Make sure n is a power of 2
// if (n != (1 << m))
//    throw new RuntimeException("FFT length must be power of 2");

// precompute tables

 for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
     cosa[i] = cos (-2 * PI * i / n);
     sina[i] =sin (-2 * PI * i / n);
 }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking what differences there are in accuracy between `float` and `double`? What results do you see in the original project, and what results do you see in your rewritten code? Are you sure the differences are due to floating-point errors and not due to a bug? Commonly, the `double` type is largely the same in C, C++, Java, and Matlab, but are variations in specific implementations, and there are differences in how arithmetic is performed. Also, the value you use for π, 3.141592 is inaccurate. You will not get accurate results with inaccurate data.

Comment: yes i ask for the acc. between floats and doubles in FFT, becouse my reslts are TOTAlly different. results is sometimes with - and origin is the with +,,, most of are values totall y different..

Comment: “Totally different” is not a useful measurement of error. If the differences between expected results and observed results are less than roughly n•log2(n)•2^-24•p, where p is the smallest power of two larger than any input value, then the differences may be normal results of floating-point rounding. This is true even if some values change sign, because the errors are affected by all the inputs and are not proportional to the individual output values. What **specific** values are you observing, what **specific** values are you expecting, and what **specific** inputs did you use?

Comment: It may be useful to exercise the FFT with mostly zero input values but a one in a single location, and to vary the location containing the one. This can sometimes reveal problems in FFT implementations.

Answer (score 3):

For most FFT algorithms, the "non-accuracy" grows at roughly at O(NlogN) with the magnitude of the input elements; and KCS/IEEE754 floats carry about 24 bits of precision.   So for FFTs that aren't super long, noise in the data, imperfect anti-aliasing, and quantization of the input are usually larger than the arithmetic error.

The results between float and double will be "totally different" only if you really care about valid and accurate data past the 6th or so decimal point.

Comment: That O(log N) error is relative to the length of the vector (the geometric length, not the number of elements in the array; that is, the square root of the sum of the squares of the magnitudes of the elements). The absolute error grows with N•log(N) times the magnitude of input elements. Individual result elements can have infinite relative error (relative to the ideal value). For 1024 elements, N•log(N)/2^24 is about 600 per million, not one in a million. “Random chance” makes most errors smaller, but some are large.